# C# Get information from a form (Like MessageBox buttons just with a form made by me)

Tags: c#, button, textbox, label, subform

recenntly I've been working on a painting software,
and i need to get information from a sub-form that contain's 3 controls:

- TextBox1 - a TextBox
- OkButton - a Button
- CancelButton - a Button

the main form contains 2 controls:

- Label1 - a Label
- ChangeLabel1TextButton - a Button

That sub-form need to be shown when i press the "ChangeLabel1TextButton" button on my main-form,
than, when you press the "OkButtom" on the sub-form,
the main form need's to set "Label1" text to the text of "TextBox1" textbox on the sub-form.

Images of the forms:

**-The forms**

[image: The forms]

**-What the forms supposed to do**

[image: What the forms supposed to do]

Hope you could help me!
Thanks anyway : )

Comment: Actually this is not quite true. Have you ever wondered how forms dialogs can block the main application loop on a ShowDialog call, still handle events and return a value? Here's the short answer: They manually pump events (Application.DoEvents()), plus some magic in the Application loop.

Comment: @M.Stramm OMG! I was going crazy an hour ago trying to remember `Application.DoEvents()`, but it wasn't that easy to search for on google either. Thank you! =) (What a coincidence..)

Comment: Have a class which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. bind the label of the Main Form to a string property in that class (using the `DataBinding` feature - you can do it in DesignView itself). Set the `textbox data` (basically, set the string property on the data binding you created in Main form) **from the sub-form** (on OK button click).  So, whenever the data is set in sub-form, the property will be updated & the main form's `LABEL` field will be updated _automatically_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get you started,

1. In your sub-form, create a public property (let's call it InputText) that returns the text of the textbox.
2. In your main-form, open the sub-form (.ShowDialog())
3. After the sub-form has closed (close it when OK is pressed), use the new property (InputText) to get the text and set to your label.Text.
4. Done!

Comment: You really helped me alot, i didnt knew this "ShowDialog()" thing even exist..
Thank you! :)